# When I try to restart Jekyll, I have to reinstall gems first

Tags: jekyll, bundler, kramdown

I am running a Jekyll instance for testing purposes locally.

When the server is running for some time (say >24h), and I need to restart it for some reason.

I get the following error when starting the server back again.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    11: from /Users/askarbektassov/Documents/Books/SDS/github/A5kar.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/jekyll:25:in `<main>'
    10: from /Users/askarbektassov/Documents/Books/SDS/github/A5kar.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/jekyll:25:in `load'
     9: from /Users/askarbektassov/Documents/Books/SDS/github/A5kar.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Users/askarbektassov/Documents/Books/SDS/github/A5kar.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/exe/jekyll:8:in `require'
     7: from /Users/askarbektassov/Documents/Books/SDS/github/A5kar.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll.rb:194:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/askarbektassov/Documents/Books/SDS/github/A5kar.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll.rb:12:in `require_all'
     5: from /Users/askarbektassov/Documents/Books/SDS/github/A5kar.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll.rb:12:in `each'
     4: from /Users/askarbektassov/Documents/Books/SDS/github/A5kar.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll.rb:13:in `block in require_all'
     3: from /Users/askarbektassov/Documents/Books/SDS/github/A5kar.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll.rb:13:in `require'
     2: from /Users/askarbektassov/Documents/Books/SDS/github/A5kar.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/converters/smartypants.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/askarbektassov/Documents/Books/SDS/github/A5kar.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/converters/smartypants.rb:13:in `<class:SmartyPants>'
/Users/askarbektassov/Documents/Books/SDS/github/A5kar.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-2.3.2/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:329:in `define_parser': A parser with the name content already exists! (RuntimeError)
```

I suspect there may be something happening with kramdown, this is as far as I can understand. The solution I have been adopting was to reinstall gems

```
bundle install --redownload
```

but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution, especially since I do not understand what could be happening under the hood.

Version information:

- jekyll 3.9.2
- bundler 2.3.8
- ruby 2.7.6p219 (2022-04-12 revision c9c2245c0a) [arm64-darwin21]

My package manager of choice is **Gentoo portage**.

Comment: Does it only happen locally or also for https://a5kar.github.io/?

Comment: Hi @Christian, thanks for assistance. It happens only locally; I have no issues on GitHub

Comment: So far, the issue seems having solved by itself, after the last update.

Comment: Current versions are jekyll 3.9.2, bundle 2.4.6, ruby 3.2.1 (2023-02-08 revision 31819e82c8) [arm64-darwin21]